# missing tags after git svn rebase

Tags: git, git-svn

I've set-up git to follow a SVN repository. Every time I want the latest changes from SVN I do

```
git svn rebase
```

That works fine.

Now a tags directory has been created in SVN and a new tag is created as well. I cannot see this changes in git. How can I get this changes into my git repository?

Answer (score 0):

My git config looked like that

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
url = https://svn.example.com/svn/project
fetch = trunk:refs/remotes/trunk
branches = branches/*:refs/remotes/*
tags = tags/*:refs/remotes/tags/*
```

(created with `git svn init -s https://svn.example.com/svn/project`)

Then added the tags and branches dir with svn (can't do that with git-svn).

after that, I was able to create tags with
`git svn tag XXX`

Then I tried what you wanted to, created a tag in SVN directly:

```
svn copy -r 17 https://svn.example.com/svn/project/trunk https://svn.example.com/svn/project/tags/lastStable
```

Went back to git and executed
`git svn fetch` and got

```
Found possible branch point: https://svn.example.com/svn/project/trunk => https://svn.example.com/svn/project/tags/lastStable, 17
Found branch parent: (refs/remotes/tags/lastStable) e8fb9785b9c23d4039dd7516931974f4ecc725ec
Following parent with do_switch
Successfully followed parent
r21 = e84f0194791f3555623280b0384f2c5531e4c579 (refs/remotes/tags/lastStable)
```

soo...I don't know exactly where your problem is.
The new remotes/tags/lastStable works fine for me now ;)

I used svn 1.6.16 and git 1.7.6